# How can I generate an error in the TryUpdateModel() function?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I will like to test the Catch branch of a Try Catch but I don't understand how to generate an errror in the TryUpdateModel(Facture) ?   I am using VS 2013 Web Express.  I tried using the F10 and it goes to the Catch but no error was generated.   I will like to be able to see and error in my return View page.

CheckoutController.cs

```
public ActionResult AddressAndPayment(FormCollection values)
{
    var facture = new Facture();
    TryUpdateModel(facture);        //I would like to generate an error here

    try
    {
        facture.DateFact = DateTime.Now; 

        //Process the order
        var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext);
        cart.CreateOrder(facture);

        return RedirectToAction("Complete", new { id = facture.FactureId });
    }
    catch
    {
        //Invalid - redisplay with errors
        return View(facture);
    }
}
```

Facture.cs

```
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.ComponentModel;
 using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
 using System.Web.Mvc;

 namespace Tp1WebStore3.Models
 {
    [Bind(Exclude = "FactureId")]

    public partial class Facture
    {
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int FactureId { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public System.DateTime DateFact { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Vous devez saisir votre Nom")]
        public string NomFact { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Vous devez saisir votre Prenom")]
        public string PrenomFact { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Vous devez saisir une adresse")]
        public string AdresseFact { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Vous devez saisir une ville")]
        public string VilleFact { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Vous devez saisir un code postal")]
        public string CodePostalFact { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Vous devez saisir une adresse courriel")]
        [DisplayName("CourrielFact")]

        [RegularExpression(@"[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}",
        ErrorMessage = "Adresse courriel invalide.")]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        public string CourrielFact { get; set; }

        public decimal TotalFact { get; set; }

        public List<Facture> Factures { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `TryXXX` pattern returns `bool` (`true` if success, `false` if fail)

So to test if your model update was successful you can do

```
if (this.TryUpdateModel(something))
{
    // success
}
else 
{
    // handle failure
}
```

The equivalent using `Exception`s would be

```
try
{
    this.UpdateModel(something);
}
catch(SomeException)
{
    // handle failure
}
```

But throwing exceptions **is expensive** so this is considered **bad practice** especially when you have a `TryXXX` available.

Comment: I just want to see the output when an error happen,  Actually I cannot change anything after I execute the TryUpdateModel code.  At the Try I cannot say it is false, anyway to perform this ?

Comment: @user3127986 I don't understand what "At the Try I cannot say it is false" means I'm afraid.

Comment: If I perform the try and it works how can't I generate an error to be able to test the catch ?   If I execute the try it goes in the return RedirectAction and never comes to the catch which I will like to test.

Comment: I was able to put the data to null and go to the catch but I was expecting an error to be given and the return view.  It just reput the data I entered the first time.  Anyway I can't get an error message back in my return view ?   Thanks